# align.time() in xts package taking huge time

Tags: r, data.table, xts

I i have ~10 GB size of file (as data.table format) which consists of 80M rows and 15 columns,
now i am trying to align  Date_time  column to the nearest 15 mins with below code

```
df$Date_time<-as.POSIXct(df$Date_time,format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")           

df$Date_time <- align.time(df$Date_time-lubridate::minutes(8), n=60*15)
```

the above 2 statements taking huge time to run .Is there any modifications required in order
to reduce the execution time?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can check `fasttime::fastPOSIXct` and for the second statement, replace it with ...

Comment: Thanks akrun, 1st statement is working fine.. can we optimize 2nd statement?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using a data.table, you should use the in-place subset assignment operator to avoid unnecessary copies. This only takes a few seconds on my workstation:

```
N <- 24*60*60*365*10
n <- 80e6
set.seed(22L)
ds <- seq(as.POSIXct("2017-02-21"), by = "1 min", length.out = N)    
dt <- data.table(Date_time = sample(ds, n), key = "Date_time")    
setorderv(dt, key(dt))
system.time({dt[, dt_aligned := align.time(Date_time - 8*60, n = 60*15)]})
#    user  system elapsed
#   2.632   0.808   3.441
```

Another issue may be that your machine simply doesn't have enough available memory. When that happens, the operating system will start to use physical drive space as virtual memory, which is a lot slower than RAM.

Answer (score 0):

After converting to POSIX using @akrun's suggestion, you might want to consider using `data.table` `roll`ing joins to round to the nearest 15mins:

```
#generate a sequence of 15mins intervals
lookup <- data.table(Oldintvl15mins=seq(from=df[,as.POSIXct(as.Date(min(Date_time)))],
    to=df[,as.POSIXct(as.Date(max(Date_time)) + 1)], by="15 min"), key="Oldintvl15mins")[,
        intvl15mins := Oldintvl15mins]

#print original sample data
df

#roll to nearest
lookup[df, roll="nearest"]
```

sample data:

```
N <- 24*60*60
set.seed(22L)
df <- data.table(Date_time=sample(seq(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date()), by="1 min", length.out=N), 1000), key="Date_time")
setorderv(df, key(df))
```